# .net core versioning hell. understanding project.json

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, decompiler

has anyone faced .net core versioning hell.  We are facing this daily in our project. my questions as below

a. understanding project.json itself looks like a big project. is there good link explaining the concepts.

b. any guideline for building class libraries that work on both core, full framework

c. guideline for referencing packages from core, dnx or full framework

whole dev experience for me on .net core has be a hell due to these versioning issues

Comment: You should rephrase your question title. It has nothing to do with what you ask for on its body.

Comment: Check the answer below. You have to forget project.json as it won't bring you any simplicity. VS2017 and the new MSBuild based tooling would further simplify the workflow and you can forget about many version numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you still need to meet .NET Standard. With .NET Standard there's no hell anymore: you develop class libraries that are compatible with .NET Framework, .NET Core, Xamarin, UWP...

See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/) to learn more about .NET Standard:

> .NET Standard solves the code sharing problem for .NET developers
>   across all platforms by bringing all the APIs that you expect and love
>   across the environments that you need: desktop applications, mobile
>   apps & games, and cloud services

Finally, `project.json` is gone, obsolete. Now .NET core works again with a more polished still XML-based `csproj` system. Visual Studio 2017 will already support that *new* `csproj`.